# How to listen to EditText changes and change ImageView Visibility at runtime?

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way that I can for example make an `ImageView` to appear only after an `InputEditText` is not null? So before the `InputEditText` has some value, `ImageView` will not appear (hidden or invisible).

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

1. in the image view's xml add the attribute:

   `android:visibility="gone"`

   or

   `android:visibility="invisible"`

   to make it invisible by default

   You can see a demonstration of the difference between the two, here: [http://tips.androidgig.com/invisible-vs-gone-view-in-android/#:~:text=This%20view%20is%20invisible%2C%20and,what%20is%20the%20actual%20difference](http://tips.androidgig.com/invisible-vs-gone-view-in-android/#:%7E:text=This%20view%20is%20invisible%2C%20and,what%20is%20the%20actual%20difference).
2. Create a listener in your activity's `onCreate()` method, to track changes in your `InputEditText`, and change the visibility of your imageView, based on the text in your input

assuming your `InputEditText` view ID is `"myInput"`, and your `ImageView` view ID is `"myImage"`:

```
InputEditText myInput = findViewById(R.id.myInput);  
myInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0){
        ImageView myImage= findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        myImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
   }
});
```